# How to have variables of one included makefile available in another makefile included later?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the `Makefile` below,

```
include settings.mk
include main.mk
```

where `settings.mk` has the following content,

```
FOO=foo
BAR=bar
```

and `main.mk` is as follows:

```
THIS_MAKEFILE:=$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

.PHONY: all
all:
        $(MAKE) -f $(THIS_MAKEFILE) display

.PHONY: display
display:
        @echo "FOO=$(FOO)"
        @echo "BAR=$(BAR)"
```

The problem is that `make all` results in the following output

```
FOO=
BAR=
```

instead of

```
FOO=foo
BAR=bar
```

How to have the variables `FOO` and `BAR` available in `main.mk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are available in `main.mk`. They aren't available in the sub-make that you are spawning because you haven't `export`ed them.

Use `$(info FOO:$(FOO))`/etc. in `main.mk` and you'll see them print out correctly.

Comment: Is `export`ing variables in `settings.mk` the only solution?

Comment: @Arman If you want the variables available in a sub-make your choices are to `export` them or to manually forward them to the sub-make on the command line `FOO="$(FOO)" BAR="$(BAR)" $(MAKE) ...` or `$(MAKE) FOO="$(FOO)" BAR="$(BAR)" ...`.

Comment: @Arman But JonathanLeffler's comments in his answer are also relevant. What you are doing here seems, on its face, to be an odd thing to want to do. Why are you doing things like this?

Comment: The thing is that `Makefile`, used as a top-level one, is a file with static content, while `settings.mk` and `main.mk` are files with dynamic contents, which may change during the development process. And there is a need to have `settings.mk` variables available in `main.mk`.

Comment: @Arman You missed the point. Why are you executing a sub-make on the same makefile like that at all? Why do you need (or think you need) to do that?

Comment: While preparing a testcase for demonstrating the issue, I tried to provide as simple testcase as possible and forgot to mention that in my case the top-level makefile is not named either `makefile` or `Makefile`. That is the reason for executing a sub-make in `main.mk`. Sorry for the confusion, guys. :-(

Comment: That doesn't answer the question either though. Why are you re-executing make *at all*? What are you doing that makes you think you need to do that?

Comment: Actually re-executing `make` is not needed in the provided simplified testcase, but it is needed for passing target-specific variable values during recursive calls.

Comment: You just said "We need to re-execute make so we can pass variables when we re-execute make" but that's not actually an answer to the question. It side-steps it entirely. What about the re-execution specifically do you actually want or need? Why is re-execution desirable?

Comment: I need to a) have `settings.mk` variables available in `main.mk` globally and b) be able to pass the values of target-specific variables (they have nothing to do with `settings.mk` variables) during recursive calls.

Comment: Why do you need recursive calls in the first place? That's the question. Why are you even bothering with recursive calls to make? What do you believe that is gaining you?

Comment: I found the [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) paper by Peter Miller from the Internet. Will read it and review all available recursive calls to make clear whether they are really needed. Thanks for your questions and support, Etan!

Answer (score 1):

When you execute just `make -f main.mk` (in the `all` target), the values are not set because you've just reread `main.mk` without pre-reading `settings.mk`.

In the `Makefile`, the variables are set.  If you add a rule such as:

```
check:
    @echo "FOO=$(FOO); BAR=$(BAR)"
```

to the `Makefile`, and then run `make check`, you'll see that FOO and BAR are indeed set.

So, the question becomes: why on earth are you doing what you are doing — and why are you expecting just `make -f main.mk` to know about stuff set in a makefile that the second invocation of `make` hasn't read?  I think this is probably an XY Problem.

You could add `include settings.mk` to `main.mk`; that might make sense (but then the main `Makefile` would only need to contain `include main.mk`, leaving open the question of why you have both).